# Disable observeChanges from update query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have multiples observeChange on a collection.
I want disable the observeChanges from update collection, someone have an idea ?

I found reactive: false from [Meteor Docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find) for .find() is there the same for .update() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [collection hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) to stop the `observeChanges` query before you update then re-enable it after you update.

```js
let handle = MyCollection.find().observeChanges({...});

MyCollection.before.update(function() { handle.stop; });

MyCollection.after.update(function() { handle = MyCollection.find().observeChanges({...}); });

MyCollection.update({_id: 'xxx'}, {$set: {foo: 'bar'}});
```

Comment: Thanks you. I implemented it differently but it's good to know